# how to catenate values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Hello,

i have a question about how to catenate elements in a dataframe. For example, i have a dataframe like in the picture.
How could i catenate 2015-10-01 with 2015-10-04, 2015-10-13 with 2015-10-15, 2015-10-28 with 2015-10-29, 2015-10-30 with 2015-10-31. At the end, i could get the combination like:

```
res=[(2015-10-01,2015-10-04),(2015-10-13,2015-10-15),(2015-10-28,2015-10-29),(2015-10-30,2015-10-31)]
```

Comment: Do you mean concatenating the value in the column "Start_Date" with the value in the column "End_Date"?

Comment: no, not simple like that. If you look over the dataframe you may notice that, when the first 'NaN' of the 'End_Date' comes out, the corresponding 'Start_Date' then concatenate to the  'End_Date' also its 'NaN' comes out. So '2015-10-01' corresponds to '2015-10-04'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If logic is join by rows with missing values in another column use `zip` with filtered rows in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with masks by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
res = list(zip(df.loc[df['End_Date'].isna(), 'Start_date'], 
               df.loc[df['Start_date'].isna(), 'End_Date']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate the value in the column "Start_Date" with the value in the column "End_Date", you can do this:

```
res = list(dataset[['Start_Date', 'End_Date']].itertuples(index=False, name=None))
```